# many js functions, show an element when any js function is executed, but hide it when a particular function is executed

Tags: javascript, jquery

My page displays titles and when any title is clicked, titles will be removed from that element and content will be produced there . I have some elements in my page(with some id) . They should be hidden when content is displayed and all other time it should not be hidden . My page switches between title, content by using the functions title(), content() . I dont want to write the code like this :

```
function title(){
    if(presentfunctionname != "content"){
         then display that element
     }else{
         hide it.
     }
 }
```

I dont want to write code like above as it needs to be written in every function otherthan content . So, is there any event listener that listens when any js function is called, so that I can check whether the target fnction is required one or not . Or any other solution ?

Comment: couldn't you just put some onclick handlers onto the appropriate elements?

Comment: JavaScript functions are a part of the language of Javascript, not the document object model.  So, no there's no way to listen for calls to functions.  I think your design approach may be a bit backwards.

Comment: Ok, then leave event listeners . What way should I go? Concept is simple . For example, display a simple form(like filter elements) all the times like when list of items are displayed . But only when the content is displayed, the form should not be displayed, as there is no list at that time .

Comment: @user1584291 You need to use the event handlers that come with the DOM and design you web page around your idea.  If you want to show or hide different page elements, you need to know when some elements should show and when they should not, then craft your code to fit into it.